# Is there a clear inconsistency with this general assertion about n-internalizations of external bijections?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, new-foundations

Define: $j^1[x]= j(x) \\ j^{n+1}[x] = \{j^n[y]: y \in x\} \\ j^{-n}[x] = \{y : j^n[y] \in x\}$

Define:
$n=1,2,3,...\\ _n\mathsf{Forth}_j(S)=\{j^n[x] : x \in S\} \\  _n\mathsf{Back}_j(S)=\{j^{-n}[x] : x \in S \}$

For any transitive model $M$ of $\sf ZF$, for any two internally (in $M$) non-well orderable sets $X,Y \in M$ that are externally equinumerous, there must exist a bijection $j$ between them such that for each set $S \in M$, for each concrete natural $n>0$, both $_n\mathsf{Forth}_j(S)$ and $_n\mathsf{Back}_j(S)$ are in $M$.

Of course this is a very general, blatant, unbacked assertion, almost blasphemous! I mean intuitively, yet it does bear some consequence, for example just working within the first two layers we get to prove $\sf Con(NF)$!

Any question about the consistency level of such assertion would be in vain, since $\sf Con(NF)$ is not finally solved yet. But, I wanted here to put such a flagrant claim to test of whether it would clearly be *inconsistent*. As that might shed some light on the possibility of consistency of this line of thought and also on how to avoid such inconsistencies if present?

Comment: I am confused, by your definition of $j^z$, $j^2[x]=\{j(y)\mid y\in x\}$ so $x⊆Dom(j)$, how $_n\mathsf{F/B}_j(S)$ is well defined for any general $S$? (That question extend to any $z\ne 1,-1$)

Comment: Unless $j$ is defined over transitive set of course

Comment: @Holo, the background theory for models here is $\sf ZF$, so Replacement works and that's why $j^2$ is well defined for an arbitrary set $x$, the elements of $x$ outside of $\operatorname {Dom}(j)$ simply won't have images under $j$, and so in reality: $j^2[x] = \{j(y) \mid y \in x\}=\{j(y) \mid y \in x \cap \operatorname {Dom}(j) \}$, similar argument applies to higher $n$ values.

Comment: @Holo, the exact formula defining $j^2[x]$ is $j^2[x]= K \iff \forall y (y \in K \iff \exists m \in x :y=j(m))$. So elements of $x$ outside of dom(j) would not be having images in $K$ this doesn't affect the result. The same argument applies for a general $S$ and for the forth and back sets. By the way I've added the condition that $M$ must be a transitive model, since this suites this question more.